# How do I put a simple transition on this button?

Tags: html, css

I've made this simple button with gradient, but how do I make the transition work? I tried using `transition: .2s linear`, but it isn't working.

```css
.contact_button {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid 4px transparent;
    border-radius: 80px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(black, black), linear-gradient(to right ,#00AEAD, #72CC50);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: content-box, border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.contact_button:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), linear-gradient(to right ,#00AEAD, #72CC50);
}
```

```html
<button class="contact_button">Contact</button>
```

Comment: Just add a transition to the .contact_button css class, transition: 0.5s;

Comment: @DragonInTraining that's the point, that does not work..

Comment: It might be because you're using gradient. Because transition should do it, have you tried without gradients and just simple background colors to see if the issue still persists?

Comment: I can't just delete the gradient, its part of the style.

Comment: You dont have to delete it, but you have to work around it. I looked it up and it seems that gradients and transitions arent best of friends. However, there are workarounds that use CSS to create the gradient transition by using small hacks. I suggest you look them up and just use whatever example fits your needs. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it differently using `mix-blend-mode` and you can apply a transition to `background-color`

```css
.contact_button {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid 4px transparent;
    border-radius: 80px;
    background: 
      linear-gradient(to right ,#00AEAD, #72CC50) border-box,
      #000 content-box;
    background-blend-mode:darken;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:0.5s;
}

.contact_button:hover {
    background-color:#0000;
}
```

```html
<button class="contact_button">Contact</button>
```